# How to show $S^1\setminus\{\alpha,\beta\}$ is disconnected, where $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm working on a problem in a grad-level Real Analysis course, and need to show that $S^1\setminus\{\alpha,\beta\}$ is disconnected, where $S^1=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ and $\alpha,\beta\in S^1$. Right now we're only looking at metric spaces rather than general topological spaces, and we are considering the Euclidean metric (i.e. $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$) on $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you draw a picture of what $S_1\setminus\{\alpha,\beta\}$ looks like, it's a circle with two points taken out. And if you think about it, open balls on the induced metric in $S^1$ are really just open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ intersected with $S^1$, which amounts to arcs of the circle. So the disjoint nonempty open sets here are the two arcs between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, a big arc and a small arc. The question is, which open balls or open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ do I need to intersect with $S_1$ to get these arcs and finish my argument? I was thinking about using an open ball with radius $d(\alpha,\beta)/2$ but I'm not sure where to center it or if that would work.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.  The rays through $\alpha$ and $\beta$ give you two open wedges that do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\alpha=\langle \cos(\theta_\alpha),\sin(\theta_\alpha)\rangle$
and $\beta=\langle \cos(\theta_\beta),\sin(\theta_\beta)\rangle$, and assume without loss of generality that $0\leq\theta_\alpha<\theta_\beta<2\pi$. (Of course, if $\theta_\alpha=\theta_\beta$ then $\alpha=\beta$ and the result is false.)

Then $A=\{\langle \cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)\rangle:\theta_\alpha<\theta<\theta_\beta\}$ and $B=\{\langle \cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)\rangle:\theta_\beta<\theta<2\pi+\theta_\alpha\}$ form the desired disconnection since they are disjoint, open, and union to your space. To prove they are open, I'd suggest proving that $\{\langle \cos(\theta),\sin(\theta)\rangle:\theta_0-\delta<\theta<\theta_0+\delta\}$ is open in $S^1$ for arbitrarily small $\delta$.